# Switch places of the Icon and Title at Navigation Menu

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I've faced this problem in android studio.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_find"
            android:title="Find"
            android:icon="@drawable/f"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_collection"
            android:icon="@drawable/c"
            android:title="Collection" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_story"
            android:icon="@drawable/s"
            android:title="Story" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_quest"
            android:icon="@drawable/q"
            android:title="Quest" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

This is the item of my **menu.xml**. now it shows in an order of Icon + Title. I actually wanna show in a way of Title + Icon. Is there any way to figure it out. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dirty solution can be as follows.

Create a layout named "item_nav_drawer_find.xml" as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:tint="@android:color/black"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/f" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In your navigation drawer menu XML, delete `android:icon` attribute and add `app:actionLayout` from the related menu item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_find"
            android:title="Find"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/item_nav_drawer_find" />

        ...

    </group>
</menu>
```

Repeat for each menu item.

The problem is that the `ImageView`'s alpha won't change if you set a menu item as checked. However, if your navigation drawer menu items are not checkable, then you can assign an alpha value to `ImageView`, as described in [guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/style/icons.html).